# What happens to the connectedness of $\mathbb R^2$ when countable many points are removed?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Does $\mathbb R^2$ remain connected when countably many points are removed? Does it remain path connected?

This is not homework but is in response to working several problems where countable or uncountable many points are removed and the pattern always holds.

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hint: how many lines go through a given point?

Namely, the cardinality of the set of lines going through a given point $(a,b)$ is uncountable.  To see this, we can assume for simplicity that $(a,b)=(0,0)$, so every line goes through the origin.  Then we can look at the unit circle centered at the origin, where a line has the form $\{(x,y) \mid y=ax\}$ for some $a$.  The claim is that this set is uniquely defined by $a$, in the sense that if $a\neq b$, then $\{(x,y) \mid y=ax\}\neq \{(x,y) \mid y=bx\}$.  To see this, note that if $x\neq 0$, then given $(x,y)$ in both sets, we find that $ax=y=bx$.  Since $x\neq 0$, we can divide $x$ on both sides to find that $a=b$, contrary to assumption.  Thus, $(0,0)$ is the only point in common, and the two sets cannot be equal.  Thus, we see that the set of lines is in bijection with $\mathbb{R}$.

From here, the idea is that given two distinct points $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ that are not in some countable subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R}$, we first look at all the lines passing through $(a,b)$ and all the lines passing through $(c,d)$.  To each point in $A$ is there is exactly one line in $\mathbb{R}^2$ passing through both it and $(a,b)$, and similarly with $(c,d)$.  Since $A$ is countable, the image of this assignment is countable, and it follows that there are uncountably many lines passing through each of $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ but not containing any point of $A$; call the sets of such lines $L_1$ and $L_2$, respectively.  Thus, we can certainly pick a line $\ell_1\in L_1$ going through $(a,b)$.  If this line also contains $(c,d)$, then we're done.  Otherwise, there is only one line $\ell$ going through $(c,d)$ that does not intersect $(a,b)$ (i.e. the one parallel to $\ell_1$ that goes through $(c,d)$), so we just pick any line $\ell_2\in L_2\setminus \{\ell\}$.

Use these lines to develop the continuous curve that goes from $(a,b)$ to $(c,d)$.

Comment: A good (nay, essential) observation, and yet I can't see how to prove this (seemingly obvious) fact. Perhaps more than a hint is in order?

Comment: I take it we are trying to show that there must be a path between any two given points which implies both path connectedness and connectedness but I can't see how to make anything more than an informal argument for connectedness.

Comment: @CameronBuie I expanded this, and gave what I think is a valid proof.

Comment: @user157227 I expanded the answer to make it a little more formal what's going on.  If you meant instead that you want a proof that deals only with the connectedness and not on the path-connectedness, then I'll have to think about it a little more.

Comment: This is perfect. If you find a proof that deals only with connectedness, feel free to post another answer, but this is more than enough.

Comment: @Hayden: What happens if you take out all the points with rational coordinates?

Comment: @Burak $\mathbb{Q}\times \mathbb{Q}$ is the finite product of countable sets, and is thus countable itself.  The answer stays the same.

Comment: Would whoever downvoted this like to point out why they did so?

Comment: @Hayden: I know it is countable, for a second I thought that when you intersect the two lines l1 and l2 to construct a curve it would create a problem at the intersection point but I accidentally removed points with at least one rational coordinate instead of two, my bad.

Comment: @Burak No problem, honest mistake.